# Compiling skimage from source on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, scikit-image, meson-build

I've spent my whole day trying to get skimage building from source on my machine Windows 10.

Compiler errors related to "-Wno" flags and C++ template errors "Compiler error C2559 'identifier': cannot overload a member function without ref-qualifier with a member function with ref-qualifier"

Attempted to fix the "-Wno-*" flags issue by going into the meson.build files and removing them, that seemed to fix that specific issue, but that is when the C2559 Compiler errors showed themselves.

Can't figure out how to change my set up to build with clang, seems like most examples online are assuming Linux/Mac and I'm failing to translate those into Windows-land.

I can't find any information about avoiding the msvc errors with compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

Making a native file and providing it to the setup via --native-file and the deleting my old build folder fixed this to build with clang

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).